# How to rasterize a featurecollection in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, rasterization

I'm trying to transform the list of administrative level 1 defined in the FAO GAUL dataset into a Image using Google Earth Engine.

I bump into the following error :

> image: Layer error: Image.reduceResolution: The input to reduceResolution does not have a valid default projection. Use setDefaultProjection() first.

What I don't understand is that even when adding `setDefaultProjection`, it's still not working.

Here is the relevant piece of code:

```js
// create the reference parameters
var name = "treecover_with_potential"
var layer = "projects/john-ee-282116/assets/fao-restoration/features/rest_pot_gt_treecoverfrac_mask_urban"

var ee_ref = ee.Image(layer)
var ee_ref_crs = ee.Projection(ee_ref.projection())

//the image is not bounded any more I need to draw it manually
var ee_ref_geom = ee.Geometry.Polygon({
    coords:[
        [-144.51600549814273, -58.07221137655366],
        [192.42150308492614, -58.07221137655366],
        [192.42150308492614, 57.78491418812651],
        [-144.51600549814273, 57.78491418812651],
        [-144.51600549814273, -58.07221137655366],
    ],
    geodesic:false,
    proj:"EPSG:4326",
}).getInfo()


var lmicList = ee.List([1,4,8,11,12,13,19,23,24,28,29,31,33,35,37,42,43,47,44,45,49,50,51,147295,57,58,59,60,61,66,63,67,68,70,71,72,73,40765,75,76,77,235,79,83,86,89,90,92,94,99,103,106,105,107,108,111,115,116,117,118,123,130,132,133,135,138,139,141,142,144,145,150,152,153,154,155,157,159,160,162,163,167,169,170,171,172,173,175,180,181,182,187,188,189,267,191,192,194,195,196,205,208,209,211,212,214,217,220,221,225,226,227,74,231,6,233,238,239,257,240,242,243,244,245,246,248,249,250,252,253,260,261,262,263,264,268,269,270,271]);
var lmic = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL/2015/level1").filter(ee.Filter.inList("ADM0_CODE", lmicList))
Map.addLayer(lmic)


// export adm0
var lmic_image = lmic
  .reduceToImage({properties: ['ADM0_CODE'], reducer: ee.Reducer.first()})
  .select("first")
  .rename("ADM0_CODE")
  .setDefaultProjection({crs: "epsg:4326"})
  .reduceResolution({reducer:ee.Reducer.mode(), maxPixels:2048});
  
Map.addLayer(lmic_image, {}, "image")
```

and the link to the doe editor: https://code.earthengine.google.com/0db6b9c48952f76dcf51945946e2beaf

Comment: Provide the scale in `setDefaultProjection()` and it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by [@daniel Wiell](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/154371/daniel-wiell) the `setDefaultProjection` is missing the scale parameter.

The error handling from GEE side is not very clear.